# function that computes the average of 20 rolls several thousand times and estimates the expectation and the variance of Y

Tags: r

I need to write a function according to the info in the title. I'm trying to perform that with the following code:

```
my.function <- function(x=1:6,Nsample=20,prob1=NULL) {

   rolling.die <- sample(x, size=Nsample, replace=TRUE, prob=prob1)

   for (die in 1:10000) {
      die.sum <- sum(rolling.die)
      average <- die.sum/Nsample
   }
   return(var(average))
}

my.function()
```

But I always get N/A as a result. Could you, please, help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need `replicate()` -

```
set.seed(2)
test <- replicate(1000, mean(sample(1:6, 20, replace = T)))

# for expectation
mean(test)
[1] 3.50025    

# for variance
var(test)
[1] 0.147535
```

Answer (score 0):

`average` is a number. It does not make sense to calculate variance of a number. What is the variance of 5 ?   Variance is applied to a collection of numbers.  So your `average` must be a vector.

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient approach is to generate all your data ahead of time. As long as you have the memory, this would be a very fast approach:

```
# sim parameters
n_rolls <- 20L #L means integer variables
n_sim <- 10000L
n_sides <- 6L

#generate data
set.seed(2)
sims <- sample(n_sides, n_rolls * n_sim, replace = T)

#make into matrix of n_sims x n_rolls
mat <- matrix(sims, ncol = n_rolls)

#mean of each simulation
rowMeans(mat)

#var of everything
var(rowMeans(mat))
```

This is around 14x faster than using `replicate` as this approach calls `sample()` once.

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
  shree_replic 137.7283 138.9809 145.78485 142.34755 147.2499 172.4633    10
 cole_samp_mat  11.3998  11.4477  11.57025  11.52105  11.7628  11.8218    10
```

As far as your current function, it doesn't make sense - the loop doesn't do anything. It just does the same calculation 10,000 times and as @user31264 points out, tries to calculate the `var` of a scalar after the loop. I think you mean to do something like:

```
my.function2 <- function(x=1:6,Nsample=20,prob1=NULL) {
  rolling.die <- sample(x, size=Nsample, replace=TRUE, prob=prob1)
  return(mean(rolling.die))
}

means <- vector(mode = 'double', length = n_sim)
for (i in 1:n_sim){
  means[i] <- my.function2()
}
#which is equivalent to
means <- sapply(1:n_sim, my.function2)
#which is also equivalent to
means <- replicate(n_sim, my.function2())

var(means)
```

And @shree has a much more succinct version of your function.